# How to load all models with the same size and the same camera position?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm setting up a website that loads 3d models in **ply format**, and I'm using **Three.js** with his **PLYLOADER** to do that.

My problem is that every model is loading in a different position. I've managed to make them load in a perpendicular way with the ground, but some of them are looking, some are looking far away from the camera and others look like they turn around a Y axis (not their center).

This is my HTML div:

```
<div id="WebGL-output"></div>
```

This is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lesson7 = {
      scene: null,
      camera: null,
      renderer: null,
      container: null,
      controls: null,
      clock: null,
      stats: null,
      init: function() { // Initialization
        // create main scene
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0xcce0ff, 0.0003);
        var SCREEN_WIDTH = '800',
            SCREEN_HEIGHT = '600';
        // prepare camera
        var VIEW_ANGLE = 60, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
        this.scene.add(this.camera);
        this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);
        this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
        // prepare renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias:true });
        this.renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        this.renderer.setClearColor(this.scene.fog.color);
        this.renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
        this.renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;
        // prepare container
        this.container = document.getElementById('WebGL-output');
        this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
        // events
        THREEx.WindowResize(this.renderer, this.camera);
        // prepare controls (OrbitControls)
        this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
        this.controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        this.controls.maxDistance = 20000;
        // prepare clock
        this.clock = new THREE.Clock();
        this.scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF) );
        // light
        var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x606060);
        dirLight.position.set(200, 200, 1000).normalize();
        this.camera.add(dirLight);
        this.camera.add(dirLight.target);
        // load models
        this.loadModels();
      },
      loadModels: function() {
        // prepare PLY loader and load the model
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var oPlyLoader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
        oPlyLoader.load("../models/{{ $analysis->three_d_model }}", function(geometry) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 0 } );
            var meshMaterial = material;
            // if (geometry.hasColors) { // to fix when models will have colors
                meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ opacity: 1, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
            // }
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, meshMaterial);

            // Solution: center mesh to world origin
            mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
            var bbox = mesh.geometry.boundingBox;
            var centerVec = new THREE.Vector3();
            bbox.getCenter(centerVec); // get center of bbox into centerVec

            // move mesh so that center of bbox is placed to world origin
            mesh.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-centerVec.x, -centerVec.y, -centerVec.z));

            // proceed doing stuff
            // mesh.position.set(0, -6, 0);
            // mesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5);

            lesson7.scene.add(mesh);
        });

      }
    };
    // Animate the scene
    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      render();
      update();
    }
    // Update controls and stats
    function update() {
      lesson7.controls.update(lesson7.clock.getDelta());
      // lesson7.stats.update();
    }
    // Render the scene
    function render() {
      if (lesson7.renderer) {
        lesson7.renderer.render(lesson7.scene, lesson7.camera);
      }
    }
    // Initialize lesson on page load
    function initializeLesson() {
      lesson7.init();
      animate();
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
      window.addEventListener('load', initializeLesson, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
      window.attachEvent('onload', initializeLesson);
    else window.onload = initializeLesson;
</script>
```

I need help to make them all load with the same camera position, looking centred and in the same size.

PS: If i can have better results loading in different extension, I'm up for it.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
I updated the code with the help of @alex. Now my models are very well centered. The only thing missing now si a fixed camera position however the model was saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently see two solutions here ( if i understand correctly )

1. You objects are not centered correctly. The solution would be to open the model files in a 3d editor and set them all to the same size and make their center points consistent.
2. Once you load the model add it to an Object3D and find its center.

Docs about that here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D

the below code this.objectAll is the Object3D. Which is put into a box and we make the controls look at the center of that box. If all model are consistent then this should work.

```
    this.boundingBox = new THREE.Box3();
    this.boundingBox.setFromObject(this.objectAll);
    this.boundingBox.center(this.controls.target);
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm still a newbie in the 3D world, I just started using threejs a week ago so i wouldn't understand how to integrate this code and there are many object that it will b tiring to center each and everyone of them.
Can you help me set up a fixed camera position for every model ?

Comment: Your line this.controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0); is where you camera will look. current 0, 0, 0. you want to figure out the central point of your model and  pass that to your controls target.

Comment: After trying out this solution once again, the objects were centred and the camera was okay. Thanks for sharing :)